# Warum haben Stadtnamen keine Artikel?

Tags: article, place-name, proper-noun

Bei vielen Namen können Artikel benutzt werden, z.B.:

> Darf ich vorstellen: das ist **der Michael**.
>
> In Asien liegt **der Himalaya**.

Auch wenn man den Artikel im ersten Satz weglassen könnte, ist er doch möglich und wird auch verwendet.

Wie kommt es, dass ein Artikel vor Stadtnamen falsch klingt und ist?

Beispiel:

> In Deutschland liegt **das Berlin**.

-> kein Artikel möglich.

Warum ist das so? Gibt es dafür einen Namen oder eine Regel, die erklärt, warum es vor Stadtnamen keine Artikel gibt? (Im speziellen bezüglich der geographischen Lage, so wie in den Beispielen)

Comment: Bei Eigennamen werden im allgemeinen **keine** Artikel benutzt. Deine Grundannahme ist falsch und *der Himalaya* ist die Ausnahme*.

Comment: Bei 'die Alpen' gänge es auch und auch bei weiteren Gebirgen. Ich habe meine Frage nochmal angepasst bezüglich der 'Allgemeinheit'.

Comment: Stimmt, aber das trifft nicht ganz den Kontext, auf den ich anspielen möchte. Hab's nochmal ergänzt.

Comment: Akzeptiert man die Regel, dass Eigennamen *keine* Artikel tragen, ist es ein bißchen müßig zu fragen, "wenn a, b, und c Ausnahmen von dieser Regel sind, warum ist dann x keine" - x ist eben keine.

Comment: Das klingt einleuchtend :)

Comment: @IQV, es müsste heißen: “Das Berlin des 19. Jahrhunderts war hübscher als das heutige (Berlin)“, denn sonst würde ein Ort (Berlin) mit einer Zeit (heute) verglichen werden. Was den Artikel betrifft, stimme ich Ihnen zu.

Comment: Welcher Michael?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die grundsätzliche Regel lautet:

> Eigennamen stehen in der Regel ohne Artikel

An sich reicht das schon als Antwort, steht trotzdem einer da, ist es entweder eine akzeptierte Ausnahme, oder falsch. Diese grundsätzliche Regel kommt allerdings mit sehr vielen Ausnahmen. Dein *Berlin*-Beispiel ist keine davon.

Dein erstes Beispiel, *der Michael*, ist genaugenommen auch falsch, wird aber in der Umgangssprache akzeptiert und verwendet. Aber Vorsicht, Artikel vor Eigennamen, vor allem vor Nachnamen, können auch eine abwertende Notation transportieren:

> Die Müller war bei der letzten Weihnachtsfeier wieder total besoffen.

Namen von Bergen und Gebirgen sind eine andere Ausnahme. Sie bekommen - genauso wie Flüsse, Meere, Seen und Gestirne - *immer* den bestimmten Artikel.

Darüber hinaus gibt es die Regel, dass Eigennamen, *die ein Attribut* haben, ebenfalls einen Artikel bekommen:

> das wiedervereinigte Deutschland
>
> das geteilte Berlin

Einen schönen Überblick über die meisten Ausnahmen von der Regel gibt es [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Namen.html), ich glaube, die komplette Liste würde zu lang.

Comment: Klasse Antwort! Danke!

Comment: "Artikel vor Eigennamen, vor allem vor Nachnamen, können auch eine abwertende Notation transportieren" - das ist aber vorrangig dem Weglassen des Titels geschuldet. Vergleiche "Die Frau Müller hat eine Lösung für das Problem gefunden." und "Die Müller hat eine Lösung für das Problem gefunden."

Comment: @äüö Gilt das auch für *den Feldberg* und *den Palatin* oder gar *den Bungsberg* (168m) in Schleswig-Holstein, die im Vergleich relativ felsfrei und auch nicht besonders "bergig" sind? Bin nicht so sicher...

Comment: Gestirne bekommen immer den bestimmten Artikel? Wenn bei [Jupiter (Planet)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_(Planet)) oder [Alpha Centauri](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri) überall *der Jupiter* bzw. *der Alpha Centauri* stünde, würde ich sagen dass ein Schwabe die Artikel geschrieben hat. Sonne, Venus, Erde, (Erd-) Mond und Mars halte ich eher für Ausnahmen.

Comment: @Raketenolli sag' das mal WIkipedia: *Namen von Flüssen, Meeren, Gestirnen und Gebirgen tragen dagegen stets einen bestimmten Artikel vor sich.* und Duden, sowie Canoo: *Die Namen von ... und Gestirnen stehen immer mit dem bestimmten Artikel*. Möglicherweise sitzen da ja auch Schwaben...

Comment: In [Darski - Deutsche Grammatik: Ein völlig neuer Ansatz](https://books.google.de/books?id=OuYH0g_M2F0C&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=Die+Namen+von+...+und+Gestirnen+stehen+immer+mit+dem+bestimmten+Artikel&source=bl&ots=hp02eTdlJs&sig=OTtIu8Nhfr7ayFPaBaeMXsJPo74&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB3oqSl_LUAhVCKVAKHc1XDkwQ6AEIUTAJ#v=onepage&q=Die%20Namen%20von%20...%20und%20Gestirnen%20stehen%20immer%20mit%20dem%20bestimmten%20Artikel&f=false) habe ich einen Hinweis auf die Diskrepanz gefunden: "Der bestimmte Artikel eröffnet eine Substantivphrase, die im weiten Sinne als bekannt gilt. Als bekannt gelten [...]"

Comment: @Raketenolli Interessante Idee. Aber dazu bräuchte man eine Umfrage, wie *bekannt* **der** *Mauna Kea*, **der** *Aconcagua* und **der** *Kangchendzönga* so sind, dass sie einen Artikel tragen dürfen. Ich denke, wer mehr als zwei der drei *kennt*, lügt oder ist Geographieprofessor. Nein, ich fürchte, das funktioniert irgendwie nicht...

Comment: "[...] die Namen der [...] Gestirne (*der Mond*)". Das erklärt, warum zumindest ich bestimmte Artikel nur mit den Namen der bekanntesten und am häufigsten gebrauchten Gestirnen in Verbindung bringe (s. o.; ggf. noch Jupiter, Saturn, Pluto, Orion u. a.). Unbekannte(re) Himmelskörper wie Charon, Ganymed, Betelgeuse oder Aldebaran werden meiner Erfahrung und meinem Gefühl nach ohne Artikel benutzt. Ausnahmen sind hier natürlich zusammengesetzte Eigennamen mit artikelbehafteten Nomen wie [der] Andromeda*nebel* oder der Große Wagen, analog zur Steier*mark*.

Comment: @raketenolli für Berge gilt das sicher nicht, siehe mein letzter Kommentar. Die bekommen auch dann ein Artikel, wenn sie kein Schwein kennt.

Comment: Die Behauptung, *Gestirne* würden immer einen bestimmten Artikel vor dem namen haben, ist schlichtweg falsch. Als "Gestirne" werden alle Himmelskörper bezeichnet, die mit bloßem Auge sichtbar sind, also vor allem die "klassischen" Planeten (Sonne, Mond, Merkur, Venus, Mars, Jupiter und Saturn) sowie etwa 5.000 Fixsterne. Während bei denjenigen davon, die zu unserem Sonnensystem gehören - abgesehen von Aufzählungen wie gerade eben - praktisch immer ein Artikel verwendet wird, ist dies bei Fixsternen nicht der Fall, weder wenn sie individuelle Namen tragen (Sirius, Beteigeuze, Deneb), noch wenn

Comment: ... sie nur nach der Helligkeit in ihrem jeweiligen Sternbild durch"nummer"iert sind (Alpha Centauri, Epsilon Eridani etc.).

Comment: Die abwertende Notation transportiert doch ausschließlich das "total besoffen", vgl. "Die Müller war bei der letzten Weihnachtsfeier wieder total chique gekleidet".